# Copy_to in R results in dates being converted to numeric columns

Tags: sql, r, database

I am attempting to create a small, training database for a package that I am writing. I am using the following code to create the database:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)

dat <- data.frame(name = rep("Clyde", 100),
                  DOB = sample(x = seq(as.POSIXct('1970/01/01'), as.POSIXct('1995/01/01'), by="day"), 
                                       size = 100, replace = T))

# Example using schemas with SQLite
train_con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

## create tables in primary db
copy_to(dest = train_con, df = dat, name = "client_list", temporary = FALSE)
```

The above portion works fine. However, when I attempt to pull data from the database, I see that all dates have been converted to numeric.

```
train_con %>% tbl("client_list")
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite does not have a datetime type.  In the absence of such a type POSIXct objects are sent to the database as seconds since the UNIX Epoch and SQLite does not know that they are intended to represent date times.

Either convert such columns yourself after you read them back into R or else use a different database.  Nearly all databases except SQLite support this.

Comment: Thanks so much. That makes sense!

Comment: Do you know is there any other way to create a temporary database that would work in this way (i.e. switching out something in the dbConnect statement so that it works the same way)? The real database that the end-user would be interacting with would be an Oracle database

Comment: There should not be any problem if you are using an Oracle backend.  Using the H2 database with RH2 R driver package as a temporary measure if you don't currently have access to Oracle would be another approach.  The `sqldf` command in the sqldf package might be usable. When used with the SQLite backend (which it uses by default) it automatically checks if there is a POSIXct column name in the input which is the same name as the output and will convert any such columns automatically; however, its use case may be slightly different than you need, not sure.

Comment: Thanks. I have no trouble connecting R to our Oracle back-end. That all works fine. What I am trying to do here is create a fake database/database connection that can be loaded as part of my package so that a user, if they chose to do so, can use to learn the syntax before actually interacting with our real database. All my other columns work fine, I just need a working date column as part of the training materials because when the user interacts with the real data, date columns will frequently be used. So mostly looking for a quick workaround (not necessarily in SQLite) that returns a date

Comment: *user can learn to use dplyr/dbplyr syntax before interacting with the real data. basically people do a ton of analysis in SQL directly, and I'm trying to get other people to query our databases directly in R using a database connection. However, to do so, I need to show them just how much more efficient R is at doing analysis than in SQL directly and to do that, I want to create a fake database that they can quickly load and play with

Comment: You can use sqldf to play with SQL without setting up any database at all if that is all you need to do. For example, library(sqldf); sqldf("select * from dat") . This creates a temporary database (using SQLite unless you specify some other backend), uploads all tables mentioned and automatically generates and runs all create statements, performs the select (or other operation), downloads the result and then destroys the database it just created. sqldf does have some heuristics in the interface that may in some cases automatically convert numbers intended to represent date/times to POSIXct.